# How can I send this XML request to my server and have it send to and get a response from another server

Tags: xml, https, coldfusion

My situation is I need to send an XML request to a user validation server from my desktop application that is installed on multiple users workstations. The validation server has a strict whitelist policy so they will not accept the request from multiple users whose IP would probably change regularly.

I think the solution is to have my desktop application send the XML request to my coldfusion webserver, my webserver somehow send that to the validation server and then send back the response to the desktop app. I've no idea how to accomplish this and I have very little control over the webserver, they are pretty strict on what we can put on there.

The request is pretty simple over HTTPS:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<cspinput appID="asdfasdf" appPassword="asdf1234" >
<account userid="johndoe" action="authenticate">
<password>mypasswd1234</password>
</account>
</cspinput>
```

And Response:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<cspoutput returnCode="0">
<account userid="johndoe" action="authenticate">
<returnValue>True</returnValue>
</account>
</cspoutput>
```

To be clear my issue is how to get this XML through my server and to the validation server. What do I need to use or do I need to create something that will do it? I have access to a ColdFusion/ASP Web Server.

Comment: One step at a time.  I suggest starting with sending data from the cf server to the validation server.  Think you can do that?

Comment: That is probably the hardest part for me because I've never done anything with web servers or using them to send xml around. I'm thinking if there is like some way I can set it up so if it gets a request at https://mycfserver.com/tool/apirequest/ then it would take that XML then send it to the server, get a response and send it back to the application. Again, this is out of my area so it may not be that easy...

Comment: The cfhttp tag might come in handy.  On the bright side, if you are starting with the hardest part, once you figure it out things should get easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

First, save the packet.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="theXMLPacket">
    <cspinput appID="asdfasdf" appPassword="asdf1234" >
        <account userid="johndoe" action="authenticate">
            <password>mypasswd1234</password>
        </account>
    </cspinput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then we use cfhttp to post it to the processing server.

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://someurl.com/endpoint" result="xmlResult">
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#XMLParse(theXMLPacket)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Then process the result

```
<cfif structKeyExists(xmlResult.responseHeader,"status_code") AND xmlResult.responseHeader.status_code EQ 200> 
    <!--- request was successful --->
    <cfoutput>#XMLParse(xmlResult.Filecontent)#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <!--- request failed --->
    <cfdump var="#xmlResult#" />
</cfif>
```

Notice that the XML declaration ( **<?xml version ="1.0"?>** ) has been removed from the packet, as invalid characters before it may case a java error.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can save your xml content to a variable using cfsavecontent, and then post that variable via cfhttp. Check this out: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/745-posting-xml-with-coldfusion-cfhttp-and-cfhttpparam.htm.

Then your response from the server will be something you can parse with XMLParse (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e90.html) and then use the dot notation (or map notation) found on that page to get your response values.